# PS3 dualshock 3 fails to connect to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth

I've been trying to connect a dualshock 3 controller to my Ubuntu 22.04, and despite how easy it looks on tuto and websites like those :

[doc-ubuntu](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/dualshock)

[tuto youtube](https://youtu.be/i3oZfa6LAMo)

in my case it's not at all. When connecting the controller to my machine and waiting in the bluetooth settings I do have a window asking if I want to authorize the bluetooth connexion :

[authorize bluetooth connection ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX4hK.png)

And when I do, I have a profile connexion for it in my bluetooth settings, but not connected :

[controller's profile in bluetooth settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWoLl.png)

But it won't connect when I click the connect button, it just try and come back to the state of the previous image above.

What I've tried :

1. Is my bluetooth driver the problem ? Doesn't seems like it :

```
$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: FC:77:74:7F:90:7B  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 96:6
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN INQUIRY 
    RX bytes:744946 acl:0 sco:0 events:25044 errors:0
    TX bytes:632998 acl:0 sco:0 commands:9119 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x0f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT 
    Name: 'PL290-PRO'
    Class: 0x7c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer, Audio, Telephony
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Revision: 0x100
    LMP Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Subversion: 0x100
    Manufacturer: Intel Corp. (2)
```

Version 4.2 should work just fine according to ubuntu-doc..

2. Is it something else with my Ubuntu ? Don't think so...
3. I can connect my controller via usb with xboxdrv as suggested on the ubuntu-doc page and it works, but I want it to be in bluetooth.

Here it is, I think that's all
Pls help, thks

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages **you** got on **your system**. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis. AND, watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you try to connect.

Comment: @waltinator I accurately followed it, I did not suffer typos or missed lines, and I didn't get ANY errors messages, otherwise I would have share them in my post. And I mentioned which procedure I've followed to avoid having as an answer "do this procedure" since I've already did it. I'll watch the command you mention and share its stack trace. Thks

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem and I'd love a solution so I can unplug the cable and play free ! :)

Comment: For anyone encountering this now, apt package bluez broke PS3 controller connectivity when it upgraded to version 5.64-0ubuntu1.1. The [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/2045931) gives the workaround, which is to revert to bluez 5.64-0ubuntu1. This solved the problem for me but is unlikely to explain the OP's problem as this version of the blues package only hit the apt repositories on 12/7/23.

Answer (score 0):

Found the work-around.  See my post on Stack Overflow or the original bug report:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77769154/5022999
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/2045931

- Edit `/etc/bluetooth/input.conf`

- Uncomment `ClassicBondedOnly=true` and change to `ClassicBondedOnly=false`
- Restart bluetooth: `systemctl restart bluetooth`